# React Native <Text> component inside another <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

function ActivationHelpText({onPress}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Activation can take up-to 24hrs, once your profile is complete.
                <Text style={styles.learnMoreButton}> Learn more.</Text>
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    text: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 14,
        paddingHorizontal:5,
    },
    learnMoreButton: {
        fontWeight:'bold',
        paddingTop: 20
    }
})

export default ActivationHelpText
```

I want to wrap the `Learn More` text:

```
<Text style={styles.learnMoreButton}> Learn more.</Text>
```

Inside a `<Pressable>` or `<TouchableOpacity>`

example:

```
       <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Activation can take up-to 24hrs, once your profile is complete.
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
                <Text style={styles.learnMoreButton}> Learn more.</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </Text>
        </View>
```

When I wrap it in Inside a `<Pressable>` or `<TouchableOpacity>` the styles are all getting messed up:

Before applying `<Pressable>` or `<TouchableOpacity>`

[image]

After applying `<Pressable>` or `<TouchableOpacity>`

[image]

I have tried applying both `text` and `learnMoreButton` styles to the `<Text>` component, but these styles are just getting messed up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native Text component has already an onPress prop:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#onpress

There is no need to wrap that part in a Pressable component

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to be carefull if you are wrapping Text inside Text for android you'll loose some styling...